# -webkit-text-fill-color not applying

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have styled a typographic dropcap element with the dropcap clipping a background image using a pseudo p:first-of-type::first-letter element and some styling effects. Right now, '-webkit-text-fill-color:transparent' isn't being read for some reason (is this because it's a pseudo element?). The only way for my text-clipped background image to appear is by applying 'color:transparent'. However, this means that I can't set a 'color:' fallback for other browsers. Why isn't webkit-text-fill-color working, and is there another way to create a firefox/ie browser friendly fallback?

Here is a jsfiddle of what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/v5j9mk95/

The Css:

```
    .nc-exp-article:not(.nc-exp-article-internal) > p:first-of-type::first-letter,
.nc-exp-divider + p::first-letter {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight:500;
  font-size:92px;
  line-height:84px;
  float:left;
  padding-right:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-right:5px;

  color: white;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/2f/13/08/2f13084ef9fb63af92e951ae50e80bc4.jpg');
background: -o-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0` in a media query to target `webkit` based browsers:

Below example will show white text in Firefox/IE, but in Chrome/Safari (webkit) will display your `-webkit-text-fill-color`

**https://jsfiddle.net/v5j9mk95/5/**

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    @supports (not(-ms-accelerator:true)) and (not(-moz-appearance:none)) {      
        /* webkit based browsers CSS rules go here */
    } 
 }
```

And your CSS altogether like this:

```
.nc-exp-article:not(.nc-exp-article-internal) > p:first-of-type::first-letter,
.nc-exp-divider + p::first-letter {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight:500;
    font-size:92px;
    line-height:84px;
    float:left;
    padding-right:5px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    color:white;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    @supports (not(-ms-accelerator:true)) and (not(-moz-appearance:none)) {

        .nc-exp-article:not(.nc-exp-article-internal) > p:first-of-type::first-letter,
        .nc-exp-divider + p::first-letter {
            color: transparent;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/2f/13/08/2f13084ef9fb63af92e951ae50e80bc4.jpg');
            background: -o-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
         }
    }
}
```